# 'npm install' gets stuck and eventually 'Killed' at something called 'swc...' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

Okay so I have been trying to deploy a Next app to my Ubuntu 20.04 vps but I am unable to do so. I have uploaded all the files from my local machine to the server via ftp and then after trying to install it gets stuck and then killed ( please check the image to see where it gets stuck ). The app works perfectly in my local machine.

I tried by deleting .next directory, node_modules directory as well as package-lock.json file but the problem prevails.

Here's the Node and NPM version in my local machine:

Node: v14.15.0
NPM: v7.14.0

This is the Node and NPM version in my server:

Node: v14.18.2
NPM: v8.3.0

I have also attached my package.json file incase you want to see the dependencies

[image]
[image]

UPDATE

I some how installed the dependencies but now I am getting different type of errors when I run 'npm run dev' or 'npm run build'.

Here's what I get after I run `npm run dev`:

```
[20:09] [server1.example.com boomboom] # npm run dev

> boomboom@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

warn  - Port 3000 is in use, trying 3001 instead.
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3001, url: http://localhost:3001
info  - Loaded env from /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/.env.local
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[4].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[4].use[2]!./styles/Footer.module.css
/home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/source-map/lib/util.js:101
        // above the root is a no-op. Therefore we can remove all '.

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: SyntaxError: /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
<w> while resolving 'whatwg-url' in /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url to a directory
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: SyntaxError: /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/node_modules/whatwg-url/package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
<w> while resolving 'whatwg-url' in /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url to a directory
```

This is what I get after I run `npm run build`:

```
[20:13] [server1.example.com boomboom] # npm run build

> boomboom@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/.env.local
info  - Checking validity of types
error - ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'react' declared in '.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-next/core-web-vitals » /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react' Require stack: - /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js Referenced from: /home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/eslint-config-next/index.js

> Build error occurred
/home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/source-map/lib/util.js:101
        // above the root is a no-op. Therefore we can remove all '.


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user1/node-apps/boomboom/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-generator.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
info  - Creating an optimized production build .[20:13] [server1.example.com boomboom] #
```

Comment: I am not seeing an actual error in your screenshots, please post the full error in plain text (not a screenshot)

Comment: @Ramakay There is no error. The process is getting 'Killed'. Check far left side on the ss.

Comment: @Ramakay I updated the post with the current errors I am getting. I successfully installed the dependencies. But now the issue is when I try to run the app.

Comment: I had the same problem with an angular application. Build process on modern spas (react, vue, angular) consume a lot of CPU. Use top or htop to monitor your cpu7ra, during the build and share us the result. Also if you achieve to reproduce the error with a minimal sample on github, it would be easy to help you.

Comment: @JRichardsz Yeah I had low RAM then I stopped some other apps and tried installing. It installed successfully but then new issues arose. Can you please check the OP from the 'updated' part which shows the new error?

Comment: This rare error could be related to your hardware: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input... In another way, npm run dev is jusr for developers. In a real server, you need to execute npm run build and then serve the assets with a plain and basic http server. Also if you achieve to reproduce the error with a minimal sample on github, it would be easy to help you.

Comment: I opened an issue in Next's repository. They're asking the same thing. But I'm not sure how I can reproduce the issue. May be it is unique to my situation?

Comment: I solved with the solution here: [npm install via Digital Ocean gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228066/npm-install-via-digital-ocean-gets-killed)